# cambiar dinamicamente la conexion de un dbcontext

Tags: entity-framework

Necesito cambiar la conexion (Servidor y/o base de datos) al momento de crear una nueva instancia de un DBContext de EF6.0 
Estoy trabajando con VB.Net de Visual Studio 2017
Alguien sabe como hacerlo?
Muchas Gracias
Saludos
Francisco

Answer (score 0):

> Antes de nada advertir que soy programador de C#, pongo un poco de
>   código en VB, espero que este bien.

Si usas CodeFirst basta con que a la clase base del constructor del DbContext le pases la cadena de conexión.

```
Partial Public Class Entities
    Inherits DbContext
    Public Sub New(ByVal constring As String)
        MyBase.New(constring)
    End Sub
```

Si usas EFDesigner debes modificar la plantila T4 Context.tt para implementar un constructor que le pase la cadena de conexión al DbContext

Creo que en VB el segundo constructor a añadir a la plantila T4 debe quedar mas o menos asi:

```
        Public Sub New(ByVal constring As String)
        MyBase.New(constring)
<#
If Not loader.IsLazyLoadingEnabled(container) Then
#>
        MyBase.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = False
<#
End If

For Each entitySet As EntitySet In container.BaseEntitySets.OfType(Of EntitySet)()
    ''' Note: the DbSet members are defined below such that the getter and
    ''' setter always have the same accessibility as the DbSet definition
    If Not Accessibility.ForReadOnlyProperty(entitySet) = "Public"
#>
        <#=codeStringGenerator.DbSetInitializer(entitySet)#>
<#
    End If
Next
#>
    End Sub
```

y como resultado debería darte dos constructores:

```
Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New("name=Entities")
End Sub


Public Sub New(ByVal constring As String)
    MyBase.New(constring)
End Sub
```

en el segundo constructor debes pasar la cadena de conexión.

Saludos,